# Mongodb array $push and $pull

Tags: mongodb

I was looking to pull some value from array and simultaneously trying to update it.

```
    userSchema.statics.experience = function (id,xper,delet,callback) {
    var update = {
      $pull:{
        'profile.experience' : delet
      },

        $push: {
          'profile.experience': xper
        }
  };
  this.findByIdAndUpdate(id,update,{ 'new': true},function(err,doc) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else if(doc){
      callback(null,doc);
    }
  });
};
```

i was getting error like:

> MongoError: exception: Cannot update 'profile.experience' and 'profile.experience' at the same time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case you need replace one array value to another, you can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) for update.

*(at least, present in mongo 4.2.1).*

```
db.your_collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("your_24_byte_length_id") },
    { "$set": { "profile.experience.$[elem]": "new_value" } },
    { "arrayFilters": [ { "elem": { "$eq": "old_value" } } ], "multi": true }
)
```

This will replace all "old_value" array elements with "new_value".

Answer (score 26):

I found this explanation:

> The issue is that MongoDB doesn’t allow multiple operations on the
>   same property in the same update call. This means that the two
>   operations must happen in two individually atomic operations.

And you can read that posts:

[Pull and addtoset at the same time with mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300148/pull-and-addtoset-at-the-same-time-with-mongo)

[multiple mongo update operator in a single statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823140/multiple-mongo-update-operator-in-a-single-statement)

Answer (score 3):

**Starting from MongoDB 4.2**

You can try to update the array using an aggregation pipeline.

```
this.updateOne(
  { _id: id }, 
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "profile.experience": {
          $concatArrays: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: "$profile.experience",
                cond: { $ne: ["$$this", delet] },
              },
            },
            [xper],
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ]
);
```

Following, a mongoplayground doing the work:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/m1C1LnHc0Ge

**OBS:** With mongo regular update query it is not possible.

Comment: This actually works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since Mongo 4.2 [`findAndModify` supports aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) which will allow **atomically moving elements between arrays within the same document**. `findAndModify` also allows you to return the modified document (necessary to see which array elements were actually moved around).

The following includes examples of:

1. moving all elements from one array onto the end of a different array
2. "pop" one element of an array and "push" it to another array

To run the examples, you will need the following data:

```js
db.test.insertMany( [
   {
    "_id": ObjectId("6d792d6a756963792d696441"),
    "A": [ "8", "9" ],
    "B": [ "7" ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6d792d6a756963792d696442"),
    "A": [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ],
    "B": [ ]
  }
]);
```

Example 1 **- Empty array `A` by moving it into array `B`:**

```js
db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: ObjectId("6d792d6a756963792d696441") },
    update: [
      { $set: { "B": { $concatArrays: [ { $ifNull: [ "$B", [] ] }, "$A" ] } } },
      { $set: { "A": [] } }
    ],
    new: true
});
```

Resulting in:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6d792d6a756963792d696441"
  },
  "A": [],
  "B": [
    "7",
    "8",
    "9"
  ]
}
```

Example 2.a - **Pop element from array `A` and push it onto array `B`**

```js
db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: ObjectId("6d792d6a756963792d696442"),
            "A": {$exists: true, $type: "array", $ne: [] }},
    update: [
      { $set: { "B": { $concatArrays: [ { $ifNull: [ "$B", [] ] }, [ { $first: "$A" } ] ] } } },
      { $set: { "A": { $slice: ["$A", 1, {$max: [{$subtract: [{ $size: "$A"}, 1]}, 1]}] } }}
    ],
    new: true
});
```

Resulting in:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6d792d6a756963792d696442"
  },
  "A": [
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
  ],
  "B": [
    "1"
  ]
}
```

Example 2.b - **Pop element from array `A` and push it onto array `B`** but in two steps with a temporary placeholder:

```js
db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: ObjectId("6d792d6a756963792d696442"),
             "temp": { $exists: false } },
    update: [
      { $set: { "temp": { $first: "$A" } } },
      { $set: { "A": { $slice: ["$A", 1, {$max: [{$subtract: [{ $size: "$A"}, 1]}, 1]}] } }}
    ],
    new: true
});

// do what you need to do with "temp"

db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: ObjectId("6d792d6a756963792d696442"),
             "temp": { $exists: true } },
    update: [
      { $set: { "B": { $concatArrays: [ { $ifNull: [ "$B", [] ] }, [ "$temp" ] ] } } },
      { $unset: "temp" }
    ],
    new: true
});
```