# why does my node.js endpoint for saving data into array raises error while modifying data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my `mongoose` schema I have the following model for storing users:

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String},
    our_username: {type: String},
    our_display_name: {type: String},
    hashtags: {type: [String]}
}
```

I want to create an endpoint in node.js that allows user's to update (add/remove) those hashtags, my use case scenario is that when user logs in to my app, I show him all hashtags with a simple `get` endpoint:

```
usersRoutes.get('/:username/hashtags/', functions.validateRequestsGET, function(req, res){
    var username = req.params.username;

    var query;

    if(username != undefined) {
        query = User.find({}).where('username').equals(username).select('hashtags -_id');
    }

    query.exec(function(err, hashtags){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }

        res.json(hashtags);
    });
});
```

But how can I create an endpoint that allows user to add/remove hashtags? I tried with this:

```
usersRoutes.post('/:username/', function (req, res) {
    var username = req.params.username;
    var hashtagsToAdd = req.body.hashtagsToAdd;
    var hashtagsToRemove = req.body.hashtagsToRemove;

    console.log(hashtagsToAdd);
    console.log(hashtagsToRemove);

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {username: username},
        {
            $push: {"hashtags": hashtagsToAdd},
            $pull: {"hashtags": hashtagsToRemove},
        },
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, user) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
                return callback(err);

            res.json(user);
        }
    );

});
```

and I use it with sending this:

```
{"hashtagsToRemove":["food"], "hashtagsToAdd":["something"]}
```

to my endpoint:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/randomUsername/
```

but it raises an error:

```
message: 'Cannot update \'hashtags\' and \'hashtags\' at the same time'
```

how can I modify my endpoint so that it covers the possibility of adding/removing hashtags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a `$pull` and a `$push` at the same time on MongoDB, which is not allowed.

You have two possibilities to achieve what you want to do:

**Option 1**

1. Get the user (using `findOne`)
2. Manually add and remove the hashtags from the `user.hashtags` attribute
3. Update the user `hashtags`attribute using the `$set` operator.

Example:

```
User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
  user.hashtags = addToArray(user.hashtags, hashtagsToAdd);
  user.hashtags = removeFromArray(user.hashtags, hashtagsToRemove);
  user.save(function (err, updatedUser) {
    console.log('yeepee');
  });
});
```

`addToArray` and `removeFromArray` are left for exercise ;-)

**Option 2**

You can update the user in sequence: a first request with `$push` and, in the callback, another with `$pull`.

**Feature request**

There is an opened feature request: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050
But there is no plan to implement it.

**Related issues:**

- [Mongodb array $push and $pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217874/mongodb-array-push-and-pull)
- [Pull and addtoset at the same time with mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300148/pull-and-addtoset-at-the-same-time-with-mongo)
- [multiple mongo update operator in a single statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823140/multiple-mongo-update-operator-in-a-single-statement)